# Geb Tests for pages with javascript in grails 2.3.5

Tags: javascript, grails, geb

I am upgrading from grails 2.2.4 to grails 2.3.5 and the last problem I am having is with geb functional tests. I have upgraded geb to 0.9.2.

The first problem is that it seems like it is first trying to run the geb tests as spock tests even though there aren't any geb spock tests, before running as a regular geb test.

The second problem is that in both cases when javascript is enabled, i.e.
in GebConfig.groovy

```
driver = {
   def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
   driver.javascriptEnabled = true
    return driver

}
```

I get the following exception :

```
|  ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: syntax error (http://localhost:8081/xyz/static/IKfETRJERwBRdVMGxGDGgTIvzB2B464w7472lQKpd3b.js#156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:524)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1144)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1039)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:393)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.refresh(HtmlPage.java:2234)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitNavigation.refresh(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1282)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:395)
    at geb.Page.to(Page.groovy:184)
    at geb.Browser.via(Browser.groovy:475)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:434)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:412)
    at geb.junit4.GebTest.methodMissing(GebTest.groovy:52)
    ......
 Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (http://localhost:8081/xyz/static/IKfETRJERwBRdVMGxGDGgTIvzB2B464w7472lQKpd3b.js#156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:187)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:214)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:366)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.xmlInitializer(Parser.java:2292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2184)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2170)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2153)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2130)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2104)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2095)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2086)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2077)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2068)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2059)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2025)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:1998)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:1979)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1025)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:891)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:535)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:456)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2496)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1456)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:201)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1448)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 38 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (http://localhost:8081/xyz/static/IKfETRJERwBRdVMGxGDGgTIvzB2B464w7472lQKpd3b.js#156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:187)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:214)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:366)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.xmlInitializer(Parser.java:2292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2184)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2170)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2153)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2130)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2104)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2095)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2086)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2077)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2068)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2059)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2025)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:1998)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:1979)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1025)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:891)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:535)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:456)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2496)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1456)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:201)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1448)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:524)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1144)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1039)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:393)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.refresh(HtmlPage.java:2234)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitNavigation.refresh(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1282)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:395)
    at geb.Page.to(Page.groovy:184)
    at geb.Browser.via(Browser.groovy:475)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:434)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:412)
    at geb.junit4.GebTest.methodMissing(GebTest.groovy:52)
.....
```

When javascript is not enabled, the tests for pages without javascript pass but tests for pages with javascript get the following:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Javascript is not enabled for this HtmlUnitDriver instance
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.getPageToInjectScriptInto(HtmlUnitDriver.java:639)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.executeScript(HtmlUnitDriver.java:590)
    at geb.js.JavascriptInterface._execjs(JavascriptInterface.groovy:41)
    at geb.js.JavascriptInterface.exec(JavascriptInterface.groovy:71)
    at geb.js.JQueryAdapter._callJQueryMethod(JQueryAdapter.groovy:33)
    at geb.js.JQueryAdapter.methodMissing(JQueryAdapter.groovy:60)
    at com.sra.ridge.geb.page.RidgePage.populateSecurityQuestions(RidgePage.groovy:95)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:194)
```

Any suggestions for how to handle these issues? These tests passed when using grails 2.2.3 and geb 0.9.0-RC-1

Comment: Perhaps you have a javascript syntax issue that was previously ignored/allowed. If you run it using a normal browser driver (e.g. FirefoxDriver) does it still fail? Did you look at the list of [0.9.1](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/all.html#breaking_changes) and [0.9.2](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/all.html#breaking_changes) breaking changes? And what's this about Spock running tests?

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for your response. I did check the list of breaking changes and none matched the error I was having. I tried unsuccessfully to set up FirefoxDriver & ChromeDriver. I didnt think it was a syntax issue because it was with both javascript files that we wrote as well as some from jQuery. But the issue was with the resource plugin. Setting grails.resources.mappers.hashandcache.excludes = ['**/*'] in the test environment in Config.groovy fixed the issue of the exception. In both geb 0.9.1 & 0.9.2 The tests run twice: as spock tests & as functional tests but only once with 0.9.0-RC-1.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed your main issue. You might want to just answer your own question and accept it, so people know you figured it out. As for running as spock tests, perhaps there's a similar problem, where you have Spock configured to look for some regular expression of filenames, or perhaps you /don't/ have it configured and the default changed? (I don't use Spock, so this is a guess on my part.)

Comment: Spock now comes with grails by default. I have done no spock configuration. I have no clue why it is running the tests twice, once as spock and once as functional.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error was apparently due to the hashing of javascript files by the resource plugin and setting

```
grails.resources.mappers.hashandcache.excludes = ['*/']
```

in the test environment in Config.groovy fixed the issue of the exception.

Using geb 0.9.0-RC1 fixed the issue of the tests running twice. It is unfortunate that we can't upgrade to 0.9.2 of geb.